Bash script (cron job?) to process files uploaded to a directory?
Let's say I have a tool called jpeg2txt. I need to write a bash script that:

Constantly checks if there are any new files (JPEGs) in source directory
Launches jpeg2txt on them, and writes the results to target directory
Deletes source JPEGs afterwards

Now, I'm a developer, but my knowledge of bash scripting is rather limited.
Could you point me to where should I start?
I imagine the script would probably need to be scheduled as a cron job, launched every minute...?
But two problems I can see:

let's say step 2. (JPEG processing) could take very long - e.g. 15 minutes. Will cron continue spawning new script instances every minute, which would end up in ~15 parallel jobs running on the same set of files? Perhaps instead of using cron, it would be better to have a script running in a loop (in the background, like a daemon), sleeping for 1 minute if there's nothing to process?
let's say files are uploaded to the source directory via (S)FTP. What if one file is only 50% uploaded and we start its processing? In other words, how to make sure step 2.) is only launched on complete uploads, not partial ones? Can we somehow skip processing open files?

Thanks!

Sorry, this isn't a tutoring service. We help you fix the code you've written, we can't provide general guidance on how to write it in the first place.

A good idea to solve the first problem is to move the file immediately out of the source directory, then convert it. So if there's overlap, they won't try to process the same files.

To solve the second problem, the upload should go to a file named something like xxx.jpg.temp. When it's done uploading, rename it to xxx.jpg. The script should look only for xxx.jpg, so it won't try to process files that are partially uploaded.

If you want to do something continuously like this, don't use cron. Write a script that runs a continuous loop and run it from systemd. It can use inotifywait to wait for new files instead of polling. This solves both problems, because you won't have any overlap, and you can wait for the file to be closed.

Thanks Barmar and Mou Sam Dahal for your useful tips!
I've decided to go with the inotifywait -e close_write solution, as it immediately notifies me when a file is closed for writing (= finishes being uploaded). I also didn't want to force uploaders to create additional .lock files or mark incomplete uploads with .temp suffix.
However, the inotifywait solution is still not ideal, as the script can easily miss new events while executing lines handling the first event. Also, unfortunately, it is not possible to combine the -m flag (= monitor events continously instead of exiting immediately after receving the first one) with -t (timeout seconds). The reason I need a timeout is that I want to wait until a batch of files is uploaded, move them to a separate directory processingDir, and only then launch jpeg2txt on all of them. This comes at the cost of 1 minute delay before starting processing, but is completely acceptable for me.
So, here's my final(?) script. I've also added some logging.
PS. Still have no slightest idea why do I need to put filename wildcards OUTSIDE of quotes, like "$uploadDir"/* ???
#!/bin/sh

uploadDir=/home/me/upload
outputDir=/home/me/output
processingDir=/home/me/input

mkdir -p "$processingDir"

# infinite loop
while true; do
  # keep on moving completed uploads from $uploadDir to $processingDir
  # time out after 1 idle minute
  while true; do
    uploadedFile=$(inotifywait -rq -e close_write -t 60 "$uploadDir" --format "%w%f")
    if [ -z "$uploadedFile" ]; then break; fi
    mv -f "$uploadedFile" "$processingDir"
  done

  # move any remaining leftover files from $uploadDir to $processingDir
  # there's a race condition here, but gee, oh well
  mv -f "$uploadDir"/* "$processingDir" &>/dev/null

  processingDirNotEmpty=$(find "$processingDir" -type f -print -quit)
  if [ -n "$processingDirNotEmpty" ]; then 
    now=$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S)
    mkdir -p "$outputDir/logs"
    jpeg2txt "$processingDir" "$outputDir" &>"$outputDir/logs/$now.log"
    rm -rfd "$processingDir"/*
  fi
done


I would do something like this:
doit() {
    # Possibly make and clean up processing dir here
    jpeg2txt "$1" "$outputDir"
}
export -f doit
export outputDir

inotifywait -qmre MOVED_TO -e CLOSE_WRITE --format %w%f inputdir |
  parallel --tag doit >"$outputDir/logs/log" 2>&1


For your case, you can create a .lock file which will make sure that the file is being processed and shouldn't be processed again, like below,
#!/bin/bash

source_dir="source"
target_dir="target"

while true; do
    # Check for new JPEGs in the source directory
    new_files=$(find "$source_dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.jpg" -newer "$source_dir" -print -quit)

    if [ -n "$new_files" ]; then
        # Process new files
        for file in $new_files; do
            # Check if the file is complete (see the next section)
            if is_file_complete "$file"; then
                # Process the file
                jpeg2txt "$file" > "$target_dir/$(basename "$file" .jpg).txt"

                # Remove the source file
                rm "$file"
            fi
        done
    fi

    # Sleep for a minute before checking again
    sleep 60
done

Ensuring complete file uploads:
To ensure that you're only processing complete files, you can use a combination of techniques:
a. File locking: Before processing a file, create a lock file (e.g., file.jpg.lock) in the same directory. If the lock file already exists, it means the file is being uploaded or processed, and you should skip it. Once processing is complete, remove the lock file.
b. Check for open file handles: You can use the lsof command to check if a file is currently open (i.e., being written to). If it is, skip processing it.
c. Check for changes: Before processing a file, record its size and timestamp. After a short delay (e.g., 5 seconds), check if the file size or timestamp has changed. If not, assume it's complete and process it.
Here's an example of the is_file_complete function that combines these techniques:
is_file_complete() {
    local file="$1"
    local lock_file="$file.lock"

    # Check if the lock file exists
    if [ -f "$lock_file" ]; then
        return 1
    fi

    # Create the lock file
    touch "$lock_file"

    # Check if the file is open
    if lsof "$file" > /dev/null; then
        rm "$lock_file"
        return 1
    fi

    # Record the file size and timestamp
    size1=$(stat -c%s "$file")
    time1=$(stat -c%Y "$file")

    # Wait for 5 seconds
    sleep 5

    # Check if the file size or timestamp has changed
    size2=$(stat -c%s "$file")
    time2=$(stat -c%Y "$file")

    if [ "$size1" == "$size2" ] && [ "$time1" == "$time2" ]; then
        # File is complete
        rm "$lock_file"
        return 0
    else
        # File is still being written
        rm "$lock_file"
        return 1
    fi
}

This function checks if a lock file exists, creates a new one if not, and then checks if the file is open using lsof. If the file is open, it assumes it's being written to and returns 1 (incomplete). If the file is not open, it records the file size and timestamp, waits for 5 seconds, and then checks if the size or timestamp has changed. If not, it assumes the file is complete and returns 0. Otherwise, it returns 1 (incomplete).
You can incorporate this function into your script to ensure that you're only processing complete files.
Note that this is just one approach, and there may be other techniques or optimizations depending on your specific requirements and environment.
